# Do multiple XML schemas in a single WSDL need to use xsd:import or not?

Tags: xsd, namespaces, wsdl, wsimport

I am new to WSDL. I have a question regarding XML schema namespaces.

Suppose I have defined three namespaces inside the *definition* tag:

```xml
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:tns="urn:arjun/ws/prime/primeservice/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:Query="urn:/arjun/xml/prime/primeservice/query" 
    xmlns:Data="urn:/arjun/xml/prime/primeservice/data" 
    targetNamespace="urn:arjun/ws/prime/primeservice/" >
```

And when I am defining a type in one of the namespaces do I need to import other namespace if I need a reference to that namespace (like in the below example)

```xml
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:arjun/ws/prime/primeservice/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <xsd:import namespace="urn:/arjun/xml/prime/primeservice/query"/>

        <xsd:element name="Input" type="tns:Input"/>
        <xsd:complexType name="Input">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="Query:StanderedInput"/> 
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        ...
    </xsd:schema
</types>
```

or I can simply refer to it without importing that namespace?

Answer (score 2):

> can i simply refer it with out importing that namespace ?

No, you cannot.  Without the import, you should get an XSD error.

In an XSD schema document, the `xsd:import` element serves one mandatory and one optional purpose.

- It signals that some of the schema components declared in the schema document may depend on components declared in another namespace; the `namespace` attribute identifies that other namespace.
- Optionally, it may also use the `schemaLocation` attribute to specify a location where a schema document for the imported namespace can be found; processors may or may not pay any attention to that information.

Comment: I am not getting any error even though i am not adding the import statement.I have checked using browser as well as soap client.So i am little bit confused.

Comment: I'm a little confused, too.  Does the SOAP client you use perform XSD schema validation?  No web browsers I know of do, so that's not surprising (unless you meant some other kind of browser, which does perform XSD schema-validity assessment).

Comment: Yes i believe. If not given default namespace or if i simply given some data type . it is validating an giving me proper error message. But here i am not getting any error. Is it because i have already added the namespaces in the definition tag ?.  You can see it in the top of the wsdl. But i tried like removing the xmlns:Query and xmlns: data , from definition tag and and included in the import statement. That time also i am getting the validation error message. how the wsdl able to identify the types which i have mentioned in some other schema of the same WSDL  with out the import statement.